# For how many positive values of $n$ are both $\frac n3$ and $3n$ four-digit integers?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

For how many positive values of $n$ are both $\frac n3$ and $3n$ four-digit integers?

Any help is greatly appreciated. I think the smallest n value is 3000 and the largest n value is 3333. Does this make sense?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your answer makes sense.

Minimum 4 digit number is $1000$

Maximum 4 digit number is $9999$

$$max = 3n = 9999$$

$$n_{max}=3333$$

$$min=\frac{n}{3}=1000$$

$$n_{min}=3000$$

Keep in mind that n must be divisible by 3. So, the answer would be: $$\frac{3333-3000}{3}+1=112$$

Answer (score 4):

112 values is the number of positive values whose n/3 and n*3 both are 4-digit numbers.

Answer (score 4):

The question is asking how many values of n satisfy

- $n \in \mathbb{N}$
- $3n \in [1000, 9999]$
- $\frac n3 \in [1000, 9999]$

So find the *min* value of $n$ satisfying the lower bound:

$$ \frac n3 \ge 1000 $$

And the *max* value of $n$ satisfying the higher bound:

$$ 3n \le 9999$$

Now only include values in the range $[3000, 3333]$ where $\frac n3$ is an integer (adding 1 since $3000$ is divisible by $3$).

$$ \frac {3333}{3} - \frac {3000}{3} + 1 = 112 $$

Answer (score 3):

To be absolutely clear: $n$ is a positive integer, right?

Then for $\frac{n}{3}$ to be a $4$-digit number, you need $2999 < n < 29998$. But you also have to consider that not all those numbers are multiples of $3$.

But for $3n$ to be a $4$-digit number, you need $333 < n < 3334$.

These two ranges overlap, so the answer is simply to count up the multiples of $3$ in the overlap of $2999 < n < 3334$.

Answer (score 0):

Some basic thoughts.

1) $\frac n3 < n < 3n$

2) If $k$ has four digits then $1000 \le k \le 99999$.

So therefore

$1000 \le \frac n3 < n < 3n \le 9999$

So

$1000 \le \frac n3 \implies 3000 \le n$.

And $3n \le 9999\implies n \le 3333$.

So $3000 \le n \le 3333$.

A third thing to note is

3) if $\frac n3 \in \mathbb Z \iff 3|n$ so

the question becomes:  How many multiples of $3$ are there between $3000$ and $3333$ inclusively.

One final basic thought

4)  For any set of consecutive integers every $n$th one of them will be divisible by by $n$.

So between $3000$ and $3333$ inclusively, there are $3334$ integers (don't forget to count $3000$ as the *first* one and $3001$ as the *second* one) so there are about $\frac {334}3 = 111\frac 13$ multiples of $3$.

Of the $333$ integers between $3001$ and $3333$ exactly $\frac 13$ of them, $111$ are divisible by $3$. But $3000$ is also divisible by $3$ so that is $112$ multiples of $3$.

They are:  $3000, 3003,3006,.......,3327, 3330, 3333$.